# What do I do with questions that can no longer be answered?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently came across this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652157/pygame-fullscreen-resolution-display-issue#comment62871168_37652157

The OP stated in the comments that they made a mistake and realized the problem was not a programming issue, now the question is sat there taking up space

What do we do with these dead questions? Ask the user to delete them? Or leave them be?

Also another slightly different question / topic: [Pygame Key Listener for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876829/pygame-key-listener-for-python-3/37023405#37023405)

The OP answered their own question in the comments and left it. I left an answer for future users to be able to quickly see, is this the right way to handle this?

**Note:** these questions were asked by relatively new users that may not come back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a close reason for that.

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

In scenarios such as the one you describe, you should look to close the question as this.  The OP isn't likely going to invest the energy to make the question any better or more answerable, so closure is the best course of action.

Comment: Ah, not sure how I missed this one. Thanks